# how concatenate multiple line with one line

Tags: linux, concatenation

I want to do this but I dont know how :

file1: 5000 usernames

```
root
ali
reza 
jack
.
.
.
```

output: 5000 emails of usernames

```
root@lpic.org
ali@lpic.org
reza@lpic.org
jack@lpic.org
.
.
.
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 3):

To replace the end of each line (`$`) with `@lpic.org` using `sed`:

```
sed 's/$/@lpic.org/' file1
```

To save the output to a new file:

```
sed 's/$/@lpic.org/' file1 > filenew
```